# Amazon EC2 - MindTerm Authentication failed, permission denied

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to my Amazon Linux instance using the Java SSH Client directly from my browser.

I have filled in the fields as shown:

Public IP: 54.194.199.112

User name: ec2-user

Key name: amazon-linux.pem

and provided the path to it.

However, when I click on the option to 'Launch SSH Client' I get the following error message in MindSet:

"Authentication failed, permission denied".

I have successfully managed to connect via a terminal window using:

ssh -v -i amazon-linux.pem ec2-user@54.194.199.112

Some info that may help:

AMI ID amzn-ami-pv-2013.09.2.x86_64-ebs (ami-5256b825)

Public IP 54.194.199.112

Instance ID i-2e588661

Public DNS ec2-54-194-199-112.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I've tried creating new instances, relaunched them, new security groups, key pairs and trawled through the forums without any luck.

I've also tried connecting via Safari and Firefox without any luck.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full Path to the amazon-linux.pem (e.g. c:\folder\amazon-linux.pem), not just the folder path (even though the keyname is in the field above it).  That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a key pair using the mindterm ssh by selecting create key pair option from the file menu of mindterm, After finishing the process, one key is placed in your hard drive now this is the private key, and open a text file in your hard drive and right click with your mouse and select the paste option, now this is the public key, add this public key line to the authorizedkey file in your amazon server.
now lanuch your mindterm ssh ,enter server ip and username, select the login type as public key, and browse the generated private key in your system and press the connect button.

i have done this process for connecting my amazon server through mindterm ssh and i succeeded.